# How to fetch data from database and display it in a drop down list using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I collect data from the database table and display it in the drop-down list, here's what I've done so far

THIS IS MY CONTROLLER:

```
public function assign_hostel() {
        $inner_page_title = 'Assign Hostel'; 
        $this->admin_header('Assign Hostel', $inner_page_title);
        $data['hostel'] = $this->hostel_model->get_hostel();    
        $this->load->view('admin/hostel/assign_hostel');
        $this->admin_footer();
    }
```

THIS IS MY MODEL:

```
public function get_hostel() { //get all hostel
        $this->db->order_by('hostel_name', 'asc');
        return $this->db->get_where('school_hostel',  array('hostel_name' => 
        $hostel_name)->result();
    }
```

MY VIEW:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label">Select Hostel</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="state_of_origin" required>
           <option value="">-Select-</option>
             <?php 
             $hostel_name = get_hostel();
             foreach ($hostel_name as $hostel ) { ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $hostel; ?>"><?php echo $hostel; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
</div>
```

Why am I getting an empty drop-down list?

Comment: Oook, and what isn't working? Empty dropdown list? Wrong order? Does your query return the wrong data?

Comment: Did you try the answers @Sylvester?

Comment: Include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @kerbholz Hi, i'm getting an empty dropdown list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Pass `$data['hostels']` in your view as given below :

First your controller `assign_hostel` should be like this :

```
public function assign_hostel() 
{
    $inner_page_title = 'Assign Hostel'; 
    $this->admin_header('Assign Hostel', $inner_page_title);
    $data['hostels'] = $this->hostel_model->get_hostel();    
    $this->load->view('admin/hostel/assign_hostel' ,$data);
    $this->admin_footer();
}
```

Second your `view` should be like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label">Select Hostel</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="state_of_origin" required>
       <option value="">-Select-</option>
         <?php if ( !empty($hostels)) {
         foreach ($hostels as $hostel ) { ?>
            <option value="<?=$hostel->hostel_name; ?>"><?=$hostel->hostel_name;?></option>
        <?php } }?>
    </select>
</div>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/index.html

Comment: pleasure is mine, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes you need to make:

Change 1:

Pass the `$data` variable when you load the view:

```
$data['hostel'] = $this->hostel_model->get_hostel();    
$this->load->view('admin/hostel/assign_hostel', $data); // $data as 2nd argument
```

Change 2:

Access key of `$data` array as variable in view file like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label">Select Hostel</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="state_of_origin" required>
           <option value="">-Select-</option>
             <?php 
             //$hostel_name = get_hostel(); NO NEED THIS LINE
             foreach ($hostel as $h ) { ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $h->hostel_name; ?>"><?php echo $h->hostel_name; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
</div>
```

I still need to know what columns you are fetching. Because in `<option>` tag you need to use the variable to access their attributes. Right now I have used the variable `$h` itself which is wrong.

You should use something like `$h->name;`

Comment: I'm fetching from 'hostel_name' column

Comment: Ok, I have used `hostel_name` as an attribute to the object variable `$h`. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get `$hostel` from view directly to model, you must get from controller and pass it via `$data` to view

```
CONTROLLER:
public function assign_hostel() {
        $inner_page_title = 'Assign Hostel'; 
        $this->admin_header('Assign Hostel', $inner_page_title);
        $data['hostels'] = $this->hostel_model->get_hostel();    
        $this->load->view('admin/hostel/assign_hostel', $data);
        $this->admin_footer();
    }

MODEL:
public function get_hostel() { //get all hostel
        $this->db->order_by('hostel_name', 'asc');
        return $this->db->get_where('school_hostel',  array('hostel_name' => 
        $hostel_name)->result();
    }

VIEW:
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label">Select Hostel</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="state_of_origin" required>
           <option value="">-Select-</option>
             <?php 
             foreach ($hostels as $hostel) { ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $hostel; ?>"><?php echo $hostel; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass $data to view function in controller
CONTROLLER:

```
public function assign_hostel() {
    $inner_page_title = 'Assign Hostel'; 
    $this->admin_header('Assign Hostel', $inner_page_title);
    $data['hostel'] = $this->hostel_model->get_hostel();    
    $this->load->view('admin/hostel/assign_hostel', $data);
    $this->admin_footer();
}
```

And in view get $hostel

VIEW:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label">Select Hostel</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="state_of_origin" required>
       <option value="">-Select-</option>
         <?php 
         foreach ($hostel as $hostel ) { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $hostel; ?>"><?php echo $hostel; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```